# Cmake configuration error when configuring opencv_contrib in Windows10

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, msvc12, opencv-contrib

My IDE is Visual Studio 2013, when I cofigured opencv_contribute, CMake_GUI ouptut:

```
found IPP (ICV version): 9.0.1 [9.0.1]
at: E:/opencv/OpenCV3/opencv/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_win
Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
To enable PlantUML support, set PLANTUML_JAR environment variable or pass -DPLANTUML_JAR=<filepath> option to cmake
Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing:  PYTHON_EXECUTABLE) (Required is at least version "2.7")
Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing:  PYTHON_EXECUTABLE) (Required is at least version "2.6")
Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing:  PYTHON_EXECUTABLE) (Required is at least version "3.4")
Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing:  PYTHON_EXECUTABLE) (Required is at least version "3.2")
Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
Caffe:   NO
Could NOT find Protobuf (missing:  Protobuf_LIBRARIES Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Protobuf:   NO
Glog:   NO
CMake Error at E:/opencv/OpenCV3/opencv/cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:857 (file):
  file MD5 failed to read file "E:/opencv/OpenCV3/build/3rdparty/tinydnn/":
  Permission denied
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  E:/opencv/OpenCV3/opencv_contrib-master/opencv_contrib-master/modules/dnn_modern/CMakeLists.txt:18 (ocv_download)


Downloading ...
CMake Error at E:/opencv/OpenCV3/opencv/cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:895 (file):
  file DOWNLOAD cannot open file for write.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  E:/opencv/OpenCV3/opencv_contrib-master/opencv_contrib-master/modules/dnn_modern/CMakeLists.txt:18 (ocv_download)


CMake Error at E:/opencv/OpenCV3/opencv/cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:899 (message):
  Failed to download .  Status=
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  E:/opencv/OpenCV3/opencv_contrib-master/opencv_contrib-master/modules/dnn_modern/CMakeLists.txt:18 (ocv_download)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "E:/opencv/OpenCV3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "E:/opencv/OpenCV3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

And my `OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH` is `E:/opencv/OpenCV3/opencv_contrib-master/opencv_contrib-master/modules`.[image]

What should I do to configure the compilation setting correctly?

Comment: It seems like these are permission issues. Do you have read/write access to these file locations? Have you tried running as administrator? It seems CMake is having trouble opening these files. Is CMake installed on a separate drive (for instance, the C:/ drive), because if so, that could also be an issue as to why it's having trouble accessing these files (which are on the E:/ drive) because trying to have applications work across drives can be iffy at times if the domains aren't set up properly.

Comment: @Chris: It looks like the package attempts to read **directory** instead of file. See e.g. these lines of output: `file MD5 failed to read file "E:/opencv/OpenCV3/build/3rdparty/tinydnn/"` and `Failed to download .`